# Использование результата linq запроса в другом linq запросе

Tags: c#, linq, linq2sql

Добрый

Подскажите возможно ли использовать результат выполнения одного Linq запроса в другом Linq запросе?
например :

```
List<Member> memberList = db.Members.Where(m=>m.Year == 20013).ToList();
var result = (from members in memberList
             from documents in Archive.Where(d=>d.MemberId = members.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new ArchiveRecord
             {
                member = members,
                documentId = documentsId
             }).ToList();
```

При этом выполнение второго запроса падает с ошибкой (Существует назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader, который требуется предварительно закрыть.)

Подскажите пожалуйста где я допуская ошибку.

Спасибо!

Comment: Странно. А если убрать `from documents`, то работает?

Comment: да, если оставить memberList  все работает

Comment: О, уже теплее. А если убрать from members?

Comment: работает подобное изменение

`IEnumerable<Member> memberList = db.Members.Where(m => m.Year == 20013);

var membersIds = memberList.Select(m => m.Id);

var result = (from documents in Archive.Where(d => membersIds.Contains(d.MemberId)).DefultIfEmpty()
             select new ArchiveRecord
             {
                 member = members,
                 documentId = documentsId
              }).ToList();`

Comment: Но всё же, если _вообще_ убрать `from members in memberList ...`, так работает или нет?

Comment: да если исключить memberList  из второго запроса он отрабатывает... Но вроде ToList производит материализацию запроса ведь так ?

Comment: Я не об этом. Вот такое работает: `var result = (from documents in Archive.Where(d=>d.MemberId = members.Id).DefaultIfEmpty() select new ArchiveRecord { member = members }).ToList();`?

Comment: нет ругается на members.Id не поймет что это)

Comment: Ну пропишите там какую-нибудь константу.

Comment: Что такое `Archive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот если так?

```
var result = (from member in memberList
join document in Archive on member.Id equals document.MemberId
select new ArchiveRecord{member = member,documentId = document.Id})
.ToList();
```

Comment: вот так вроде работает )

Comment: Вроде - или работает? Исходный запрос делал операцию LEFT JOIN - а вы ее на INNER JOIN заменили.